# How do I keep the debugger attached when the code auto-reloads?

Tags: ruby, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm improving my development environment for a dockerized ruby application.

My code editor is VSCode and I am using [rdbg](https://github.com/ruby/vscode-rdbg) to provide an interactive debugger

I am also using the [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) gem to provide auto-reloading when my codebase changes.

When I start my app, should I run my auto-reloader before I start the debugger, i.e.:

```
bundle exec rerun -- rdbg -- my_app start
```

Or should I run the debugger first?

```
bundle exec rdbg -- rerun -- my_app start
```